# How to insert a long text in a multicolumn setting?

Tags: tables, tabularx, multicolumn

I would like to create a table with my some rows being multicolumns, one of them to be filled with a long text, followed by a 2 column's row. I don't have any issue to create the multicolumns or insert the long text in the typical columns but when I use the \multicolumn function my text overflows and messes up my table.

I used the following code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}  
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
 \usepackage{authblk}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{url}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[autostyle]{csquotes}  
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{ltablex,booktabs}
\usepackage[title]{appendix}

\newcolumntype{C}{>{\arraybackslash}X}
\newlength{\twocolwidth}
\setlength\twocolwidth{\dimexpr1\hsize+\tabcolsep+\arrayrulewidth}

\newcommand{\source}[1]{\vspace{-1pt}{\hfill \footnotesize{Source: {#1}} } }

\newcolumntype{b}{X}
\newcolumntype{s}{>{\hsize=.2\hsize}X}
\newcolumntype{m}{>{\hsize=.4\hsize}X}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    linkcolor={red!50!black},
    citecolor={blue!50!black},
    urlcolor={blue!80!black}
}



\topmargin 0.0cm
\oddsidemargin 0.2cm
\textwidth 16cm 
\textheight 21cm
\footskip 1.0cm

\counterwithin{figure}{section}
\counterwithin{table}{section}
\renewcommand\thefigure{\thesection\arabic{figure}} 
\renewcommand\thetable{\thesection\arabic{table}} 



{\footnotesize
 \begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}[h!]{| X | X |}
 \caption{Description of the selected algorithms\label{TABLEA}}\\

 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{Begin of Table}\\
 \hline
Algorithm & General Operation \\
 \hline
 \endfirsthead

 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{Continuation of Table \ref{TABLEA}}\\
 \hline
Algorithm & General Operation \\
 \hline
 \endhead

 \hline
 \endfoot

 \hline
 \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{End of Table}\\
 \hline
 \endlastfoot

\multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{Agglomerative methods}} \\ 
\hline
\multicolumn{2}{|>{\hsize=\twocolwidth}C c |}{The notion of distance in this family makes it possible to identify cliques through relational proximities } \\
   \hline
  
 \hline 
           \textbf{Hierarchical algorithm} with 4 different settings:  Euclidean distance / Complete linkage; Euclidean distance / Ward; Manhattan distance / Complete linkage; Manhattan distance / Ward.
           & The basic idea is to construct the hierarchical relationship among data in order to cluster. Each data point stands for an individual cluster in the beginning, and then, the most neighboring two clusters are merged into a new one until there is only one cluster left. The concept of "neighborhood" depends on the distance between nodes which is computed by squaring the Euclidean or Manhattan distances and grouping them into a symmetric matrix. The clustering method (here, complete linkage and Ward's algorithm) identifies the closest nodes to agglomerate them. We obtain a hierarchical dendogram which is cut to the desired number of clusters. \\


 \end{tabularx}
}



\end{document}
```

But the text appear in double as you can see here :
[image]

and the table become bigger than my page.

Is anyone know how to fix this please?

P.S : I am just a beginner using Overflow so I have no idea what part of the code produced that

Answer (score 3):

- It is not clear, how your table should look.
- So far it is quite unusual. For example, what you like to say with row with "Begin of Table" and "End of Table" in table head?
- Use of the `ltablex` package can be tricky.
- Package `tabu` is buggy and not maintained. Don't use it. Instead it try to use relative new, powerful package `tabularray`.
- You need to cleanup your document preamble:

  - each packages should be loaded only once
  - package `hyperref` should be loaded last (with rare exception which is not present in your document)
  - do you really need all these packages?
- You should be aware that long table can be broken between pages only between rows.

An example of table using `longtblr` of `tabularray` package, where some rows are repeated that table is long enough to span over two pages, is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[margin=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{tabularray}
\UseTblrLibrary{booktabs}  % it load package booktabs, 
                            % so delete its other loads

\begin{document}
\noindent\begin{longtblr}[
caption={Description of the selected algorithms},
  label={TABLEA}        ]{hlines, vlines,
                         colspec={*2{X[j]}},
                         row{1} = {c, font=\bfseries},
                         rowhead=2,
                         hspan=minimal}
% table body
Algorithm       & General Operation     \\
\SetCell[c=2]{c,font=\bfseries}    Agglomerative methods 
                &                       \\
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    The notion of distance in this family makes it possible to identify cliques through relational proximities
                &                       \\
\textbf{Hierarchical algorithm} with 4 different settings:  Euclidean distance / Complete linkage; Euclidean distance / Ward; Manhattan distance / Complete linkage; Manhattan distance / Ward.
                &   The basic idea is to construct the hierarchical relationship among data in order to cluster. Each data point stands for an individual cluster in the beginning, and then, the most neighboring two clusters are merged into a new one until there is only one cluster left. The concept of "neighborhood" depends on the distance between nodes which is computed by squaring the Euclidean or Manhattan distances and grouping them into a symmetric matrix. The clustering method (here, complete linkage and Ward's algorithm) identifies the closest nodes to agglomerate them. We obtain a hierarchical dendogram which is cut to the desired number of clusters. \\

\SetCell[c=2]{c,font=\bfseries}    Agglomerative methods
                &                       \\
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    The notion of distance in this family makes it possible to identify cliques through relational proximities
                &                       \\
\textbf{Hierarchical algorithm} with 4 different settings:  Euclidean distance / Complete linkage; Euclidean distance / Ward; Manhattan distance / Complete linkage; Manhattan distance / Ward.
                &   The basic idea is to construct the hierarchical relationship among data in order to cluster. Each data point stands for an individual cluster in the beginning, and then, the most neighboring two clusters are merged into a new one until there is only one cluster left. The concept of "neighborhood" depends on the distance between nodes which is computed by squaring the Euclidean or Manhattan distances and grouping them into a symmetric matrix. The clustering method (here, complete linkage and Ward's algorithm) identifies the closest nodes to agglomerate them. We obtain a hierarchical dendogram which is cut to the desired number of clusters. \\

\SetCell[c=2]{c,font=\bfseries}    Agglomerative methods
                &                       \\
\SetCell[c=2]{c}    The notion of distance in this family makes it possible to identify cliques through relational proximities
                &                       \\
\textbf{Hierarchical algorithm} with 4 different settings:  Euclidean distance / Complete linkage; Euclidean distance / Ward; Manhattan distance / Complete linkage; Manhattan distance / Ward.
                &   The basic idea is to construct the hierarchical relationship among data in order to cluster. Each data point stands for an individual cluster in the beginning, and then, the most neighboring two clusters are merged into a new one until there is only one cluster left. The concept of "neighborhood" depends on the distance between nodes which is computed by squaring the Euclidean or Manhattan distances and grouping them into a symmetric matrix. The clustering method (here, complete linkage and Ward's algorithm) identifies the closest nodes to agglomerate them. We obtain a hierarchical dendogram which is cut to the desired number of clusters. \\
\end{longtblr}
\end{document}
```

*Note*:

- Table is modified that has form as are usual used at tables.
- In preamble are loaded only packages related to this table.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Insert `\parbox` inside `\multicolumn`. It will format texts similarly to regular paragraphs, most of all it will add line breaks if necessary. It is justified by default so you might need to add `\centering`, `\raggedright` etc. to format text.

I also added `\strut` at the beginning of the text, so that the row can be slightly extended creating a small vertical gap above. If you want larger gaps, add invisible bars instead. For instance, at the beginning of the text insert

```
\rule{0pt}{12pt}
```

and at the end of the text append

```
\rule[-6pt]{0pt}{6pt}
```

Finally, `\parbox` requires a mandatory argument: width. In your case, this is a width of the text body reduced by amount space occupied by rules and column separators in the table.

Here's the part of the table with the problematic `\multicolumn`

[image]

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\begin{document}
{\noindent
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{| *2{X|}}
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{Begin of Table} \\
    \hline
    Algorithm & General Operation \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{End of Table} \\
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{\textbf{Agglomerative methods}} \\ 
    \hline
    \multicolumn{2}{| c |}{%
        \parbox{\dimexpr\textwidth-2\tabcolsep-2\arrayrulewidth}{\strut
        The notion of distance in this family makes it possible to identify cliques through relational proximities}
    } \\
    \hline
\end{tabularx}\par}
\end{document}
```